# Как удалять сообщение, если слово из списка есть в сообщении? aiogram3

Tags: python, list, aiogram

Сделал вот такой код:

```
@router.message()
async def message_censore(msg: Message):
    with open('sensore.txt', 'r') as f:
        censored_letters = [line.strip() for line in f]
    if str(censored_letters) in msg.text:
        await msg.delete()
```

Но он работает только в том случае, если `censored_letters` заменить на слово в ковычках, например `'мат'`. Пробовал выводить список, все слова импортируются.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я это реализовал вот так:

```
@router.message(F.text, lambda msg: any(x in msg.text.lower().replace("ё", "е") for x in core.swear_words_list.swears))
async def censure(message: Message):
    await message.delete()
    await message.answer("Без мата, пожалуйста ⛔")
```

Мне кажется, что быстрее будет создать python-файл со списком, чем прочитывать его каждый раз из текстового файла и не забудьте его поставить первым в аргументах `dp.include_routers()`

Comment: Работает спасибо. А может знаете как запускать функции при старте бота если туда передаётся `message`? Через старт не удобно.

Comment: @Nqweqweqwe Не понял вопроса

Comment: Вы про это? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1563465/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-aiogram-3-3-0

Comment: да я про это. Если поможете буду благодарен

Answer (score 1):

Проверку надо сделать такой:

```py
if any([cen in msg.text for cen in censored_letters]):
```

Функция [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) возвращает `True` если хотя бы один элемент переданного ей списка истинен.

Answer (score 1):

**Код:**

```py
@router.message()
async def message_censore(msg: Message):
    with open('sensore.txt', 'r') as f:
        censored_letters = [line.strip() for line in f]
    for cen in censored_letters:  # (1)
        if cen in msg.text:       # (2)
            await msg.delete()    # (3)
            return                # (4)
```

**Примечания:**

1. Перебираем все "запрещённые" слова.
2. Если слово есть в сообщении...
3. ... Удаляем сообщение и ...
4. Прерываем работу функции.